# How the symmetric groups with same cardinality can be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Intuitively I know that there are isomorphisms between the symmetric groups with same cardinality.

but i dont know how to show it precisely.

give me some intuition! thank you!

Comment: Uh, you probably don't want to say "Give me....".

Comment: @MetinY. Y.thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherErnst i dont know what you mean... I'm not english native, tell me straightforward way.

Comment: What he probably means is that this way of talking "give me..." seems as if you are demanding the answer from others. People are more likely to respond to a more polite request.

Comment: @Shahab I should look through other articles to learn how they talking:) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets and suppose there exists a bijection $f: A \rightarrow B$ between them.  Consider the map $\phi : \text{Sym}(A) \rightarrow \text{Sym}(B)$ given by $\phi(\sigma) = f \circ \sigma \circ f^{-1}$.  Prove that $\phi$ is a well-defined homomorphism and then either (1) construct an inverse homomorphism $\phi^{-1} : \text{Sym}(B) \rightarrow \text{Sym}(A)$ or (2) prove that $\phi$ is bijective.  To show that $\phi$ is well-defined, you must argue why $\phi(\sigma) : B \rightarrow B$ is a bijection if $\sigma : A \rightarrow A$ is.